# Abortar llamada post al servidor asp.net por tiempo de espera

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo un formulario en asp.net que cuando se rellena hay un botón que lanza a otra pagina. 
A veces puede pasar que la nueva pagina tarde en ser devuelta por el servidor debido a una sobrecarga del servidor , por fallos de conexión, etc...
Me gustaría saber como se puede abortar esta llamada y que la pagina actual no cambie al tipico error 404 una vez ya he realizado el 'submit'. Sino que pueda mostrar yo una ventana con un mensaje para volver a intentarlo otra vez en otro momento.

Actualmente tengo puesto este código en JavaScript antes de la llamada al servidor:

```
function esperaPagina() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "#";
 }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Amigo, tienes suficiente reputación para saber que tu pregunta necesita código. De **FrontEnd**, de **BackEnd** y parámetros de `timeout` en **web.config** Para las caidas del servidor se maneja una clase conexión y para los paquetes muy grandes se maneja en **web.config**.

Comment: @harifopiñerarenuncia gracias por tu contestación. Tiene algún enlace o ejemplo donde pueda mirarlo.

Comment: [Enlace](https://www.techcartnow.com/increase-timeout-asp-net-application/)